# Angular UI Router state inheritance not working

Tags: angularjs, templates, view, state

When I navigate to a page, it hits a state that loads threads/main.html. main.html has three ui-view directives, two of them named, and one plain. When I hit the nested view 'dashboard.messages.default.sidepanel.default' I can see that the states templates are being loaded, but they are not being inserted into the third plain ui-view.

main.html

```
<div class="thread">
    <div ui-view="header"></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div ui-view="messages" class="messages-container" ng-class="{'hidden-xs col-sm-7': thread.sidepanel.isOpen}">
                MESSAGES HERE
            </div>

            <div class="sidepanel col-xs-12 col-sm-5" ng-show="thread.sidepanel.isOpen">
              <div ui-view>
                  <i>CONTENT HERE.</i>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

States

```
$stateProvider
            .state('dashboard.messages', {
                url: 'c/{owner}/{thread}',
                params: {threadId: null},
                resolve: {
                    threadInfo: threadInfoResolve,
                    title: ["threadInfo", function (threadInfo) {
                        return threadInfo.thread.name;
                    }]
                },
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: '/static/templates/dashboard/partials/thread/main.html',
                        controller: 'Thread',
                        controllerAs: 'thread'
                    },
                    'header@dashboard.messages': {
                        templateUrl: '/static/templates/dashboard/partials/thread/header.html',
                        controller: ["threadInfo", function (threadInfo) {
                            this.thread = threadInfo.thread;
                        }],
                        controllerAs: 'vm'
                    },

                }
            })
            .state('dashboard.messages.default', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/static/templates/dashboard/partials/thread/messages.html',
                controller: 'Messages',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                resolve: {
                    threadInfo: threadInfoResolve,
                },
            })
            .state('dashboard.messages.default.sidepanel', {
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: '/static/templates/dashboard/partials/thread/sidepanel.html',
                controller: 'Sidepanel',
                controllerAs: 'sp'
            })
            .state('dashboard.messages.default.sidepanel.default', {
                url: 'info',
                templateUrl: '/static/templates/dashboard/partials/thread/info.html',
                controller: 'Info',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
    }
```

Comment: This is way too much code and I'm having hard time understanding your issue. Please keep only relevant code and try to explain your issue before providing any code at all.

Comment: I deleted all of the states that weren't being hit yet, and weren't necessary for the question so it would be a little less code. My issue is now that the state 'dashboard.message.default.sidepanel.default' is being hit, and the templates are being loaded, but they aren't going into the third ui-view on my main.html.

Comment: `templateUrl` refers only to the innermost, non-named `ui-view` **inside the parent state template**, if you want to change parent view you need to use the full state path like you did in the second one.